# Properties of logarithms $e^{\ln(x)}$ and corollaries

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $e^{\ln(x)} = x$, does
$$e^{\ln(\tan(\pi x/2))} =\tan(\pi x/2)$$

If not, what does the function equal and why?

Comment: Yes, it does. $e^{ln(u)}=u$.

Comment: This can even be made true when $\tan(\pi x/2)$ is negative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $u=\tan{\frac{\pi x}{2} }$, then we have $e^{\ln{u}}=u.$ This is your first sentence, which is true!

Answer (score 0):

If we are concerning ourselves with complex numbers, then this statement is valid for all x. If we are not, this is only valid for $\tan(\frac{\pi x}{2})>0.$